# Using Kendo ui web in mobile

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, telerik, kendo-ui

As per the FAQ, its possible to use a Kendo UI widget in a mobile application. I tried this by including references to these js scripts:

```
    jquery-1.7.1.js
    kendo.core.js
    kendo.fx.js
    kendo.popup.js
    kendo.calendar.js
    kendo.datepicker.js
```

and initialized it using:

```
$("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker();
```

but it never gets rendered correctly. Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yo

I am not sure what you might miss - [here](http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/javascript-dependencies.aspx) you can see all the JavaScript dependencies.
Also make sure you have added the CSS files.

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.322/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.322/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.322/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: The widgets of Kendo UI Web have JavaScript and CSS dependencies. In the case of the former, it's jQuery. In the case of the latter, it's the stylesheets provided on the CDN as cited by XMR. Please note that the version number will change from release to release.

Answer (score 0):

It might sound funny but did u create a kendo Application object(u have'nt mentioned that u did in your question), if u did not, create a kendo application object, something like -

```
var application = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document).body, { transition:"slide" });
```